# Drupal 7 Remove field suffix from search index

Tags: search

On my Drupal 7 installation I have many different custom fields with different suffixes. Drupal inserts the suffixes into the search_index table which I need to avoid. I could change the output, so that the suffixes are hardcoded on the template side and only shown if the specific fields are printed, but I don't like this solution.

Is there any other way to tell Drupal which fields to add to search_index and which fields to skip? Any hook I could use?

I'm not sure if I really want to use the Search API Module...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude fields from being added to the search index under the settings for you content type.

[image: exclude fields from drupal core search index]

Go to the settings for you content type and Manage display. Click on the view mode Search index and drag the fields you don't want to index to Hidden.

Comment: Oh,, missed your part on suffixes. Hmm. trying changing format to plain text and see if that does the trick.